# Sharing std::function across many modules with limited life-times

Tags: c++, c++11, dll

I'm creating a std::function on a module and sharing it to another module. The module that created the std::function has a limited life-time, as such when the other module tries to free the std::function, it's not capable since the module has been freed already.

```
// A.dll
// A.h
__declspec(dllexport) void add_handler(std::function<void()> _handler);

// A.cpp
std::function<void()> handler;
void add_handler(std::function<void()> _handler)
{
   handler = _handler;
}

// B.dll
void main(void)
{
   std::function<void()> handler_tmp = []()
   {
      // something
   };

   add_handler(handler_tmp);
}
// B.dll is freed before A.dll
```

How do I safely create an std::function inside B.dll and share it with A.dll when B.dll might get freed before A.dll?

Comment: I don't think you'll have any luck there, as it's near-impossible to guarantee that all relevant code is still mapped after unloading the creating module.

Comment: I'm thinking the only way will be to instantiate an RAII object globally in B.dll that destroys all of the handlers on dtor.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few items to note here.  First, as you point out in your comment, if an object adds a handler, it should probably remove it.  So you make a good point with respect to the RAII object.

```
class B
{
public:
    B() { add_handler([](){ /* handler code */ }); }
    ~B() { add_handler(nullptr); }
};
```

In your example above, the dll will unload when leaving main.  I understand your above code is a very simple example, and is conceptual.  Nevertheless, scope of the lambda here is important, and may have some unintended consequences.  Take for instance:

```
// B.dll
void main(void)
{
    { // <-- providing arbitrary scope for b
        B b { };
        // [ call other functions on b ]
    }

    // [ additional code which ends up calling the handler ]
}
```

As you know, std::function is just a wrapper for a callable object.  In the code above (copyable function object), even without the dtor on B, the code will execute the handler without issue.  'b' is no longer in scope, but a copy of the lambda was moved (in its entirety, including any captured values and references) into the std::function which is held globally, and will remain valid as long as the global handler holds onto it.

Trace into each assignment, and you will see that the entire lambda is being passed [R-Value Ref] and forwarded, and swapped. Obviously, since the real implementation of this handler will likely operate on 'b' in some way, this is not desirable.  But one of beauties of C++ is not to make you pay for the overhead of handling all of these scenarios, and performing the cleanup, then care must be taken.